# Observing changes to inner arrays in a viewmodel created the knockout mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I'm using the knockout mapping plugin to create a viewmodel from data that has inner arrays.
I can get the html to load correctly and get the add and remove functions in my viewmodel to make the changes required to the DOM. but when I try to save the changes using stringifyJson the string is undefined.

```
var viewModel = {
groupItem: ko.observableArray(),
add: function() {
    this.scheduleitems.push({
        time: ko.observable("03:00"),
        LL: ko.observable(""),
        L: ko.observable(""),
        H: ko.observable(""),
        HH: ko.observable("")
    });
   },
   remove: function(item,parent) {
        parent.scheduleitems.remove(item);
},
save: function() {
    var data = ko.utils.stringifyJson(this.groupItem);
    console.log(data);
}
};

var data3 = [
{
        "title": "P1 Alarms",
        "id": "dadas-sadf-asdf-asd",
        "behaviouritems": [
            {"title": "GPRS","LL": true,"L": false,"H": true,"HH": false},
            {"title": "SMS","LL": false,"L": false,"H": false,"HH": true},
            {"title": "Software","LL": false,"L": false,"H": true,"HH": false}
        ],
        "scheduleitems": [
            {"time": "00:00","LL": false,"L": false,"H": false,"HH": true},
            {"time": "02:00","LL": true,"L": false,"H": false,"HH": false}
        ]
}]

ko.mapping.fromJS(data3, null, viewModel.groupItem);
console.log(viewModel.groupItem);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("customerDiv"));
```

here is a fiddle of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/davidoleary/q2BSZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid this was a mistake, I shouldn't have used stringifyJson. I found that I get the expected results including all changes made via the UI, if I user either of the following.

```
var result = ko.mapping.toJS(this);
console.log(result );

var jsonResult = ko.mapping.toJSON(this);
console.log(jsonResult);
```